# "&laquo + json_encode" что то не пойму

Tags: json, php

Пишу скрипт:

```
$ff = '«';
echo $ff.'<br>';
echo json_encode(array('data'=>$ff));

//Вывод:
//«
//{"data":"\u00ab"}
```

Пишу второй:

```
$ff = html_entity_decode('&laquo;');
echo $ff.'<br>';
echo json_encode(array('data'=>$ff));

//Вывод:
//«
//{"data":null}
```

Вместо `html_entity_decode('&laquo;')` можно писать `chr(171)`. Результат такой же, wtf? Чем объяснить?

P.S. Система в utf-8

Comment: У меня другие результаты, это подтвердилось на IDEone:  
http://ideone.com/ZgYip3  
Попробуйте явно задать кодировку по умолчанию:  

    ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');

Comment: Не помогло. Хреново...

Comment: Да. У меня такие же результаты на локалхосте.

Comment: Так:  

    setlocale( LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8" );
или так (предпочтительнее) :  

    html_entity_decode('&laquo;', null, "UTF-8")

Comment: Предполагаю, что в ideone данные на сервер уходят уже закодированные(не проверял). Сейчас попробую другие варианты

Comment: Впечатанный скрипт просто исполняется в песочнице, если не ошибусь. То что была отправка браузером не влияет насколько мне известно.

Comment: html_entity_decode('&laquo;', null, "UTF-8") работает. Только вот на локалхосте нормально, а если на продакшен закомичу? Если на серваке винда? Стремно пробовать. У вас utf-8 в системе?

Comment: На продакшне тоже успешно отработает, можете не сомневаться.  
В системе наверно ср1251, php и apache настроены на utf-8. Сейчас соберу в ответ варианты решений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
html_entity_decode('&laquo;', null, "UTF-8")
```

Comment: Почитал описание функции [php.net: html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.html-entity-decode.php) и оказалось, что:  

> Кодировка для использования. Если не указана, то значением по умолчанию для этого аргумента является ISO-8859-1 в версиях PHP до 5.4.0 и UTF-8 начиная с PHP 5.4.0 и далее

У меня php 5.5.4, у Вас видимо более низкая версия.  
Чтобы эта функция брала кодировку из настроек php нужно передать ей пустую строку:  

    html_entity_decode('&laquo;', null, "");
Поэтому не получались манипуляции с кодировкой по умолчанию.

Comment: Точно!! php 5.3.10. Спасибо за помощь)